# Adding Safari bookmarks on iOS

Tags: ios

Is there any way one can add a URL to Safari bookmarks?

I'd like to have an extension to bookmark a webpage (opened in any app's webview).

Since it's for personal use, it can be a private way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge, there isn't any APIs to modify Safari bookmarks on iOS. But on macOS, there are ways to do it (e.g. [A UNIX script to add a bookmark to Safari](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/6031/just-sharing-a-unix-script-to-add-a-bookmark-to-safari)).

Since it is for your personal use, I suggest you to create a macOS companion app to receive instructions from your iOS extension and add bookmarks accordingly.